# Concatenate strings as a variable in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop

I have data sets stored to several variables like: p1_5, p1_7,p1_9....p1_19, and I want to calculate the std() of each data set. Now how to do it in a for loop in matlab? How to concatenate 'p1_' to n, but still keep it as a variable but not string?

```
for n = 5:2:19
    std(p1_??);  
end
```

Comment: I would highly recommend restructuring your data so you do not have to use an `eval` command as Dan had recommended in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval` for this:

```
for n = 5:2:19
    eval(['std(p1_', num2str(n), ')']);  
end
```

But you should probably consider restructuring your code to not have to. Could you store all your `p1`s in a 3D matrix or a cell array?

Answer (score 2):

You could put them in a cell array. Even better, if they have the same dimensions, stack them in a matrix.